# How does the logical implication work here?

Tags: proof-explanation, first-order-logic

[This answer (from a different post) is trying to show that one statement does not imply another](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3549756/868849).

Consider the binary relation $\succsim$ defined on $X \times X$ where $X$ is a subset of the Euclidean space (of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ dimension(s)). The relation is complete and transitive. Any element considered (below) is an element of $X$.

Statement 1: Both upper contour $\{y : y \succsim x \}$ and lower countour set $\{y : y \precsim x\}$ are closed.

Statement 2: Let $x_n$ be a sequence converging to $x$ (that is, $x_n \to x$). If $x_n \succsim y$ (or $x_n \precsim y$) for each $n$, then $x \succsim y$ (or $x \precsim y$, respectively).

**I am trying to figure out whether the two statements are equivalent.**

**The linked answer describes a counter-example to show that the second statement does not imply the first.** Here's it.

> **The second definition does not imply the first.** For a counterexample, let the relation to be such that it is represented by a function $f$ which is upper-semicontinuous, but not lower-semicontinuous.
> For instance, let $X = [0, 1]$ and let $f\colon[0, 1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function
> $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> -x \quad \quad \text{ if $x \in [0, 1/2)$}\\
> 1 + x \quad \text{ else}.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Then $x^{n} \succeq y$ and $x^{n} \to y$ imply $x \succeq y$ since $f$ is upper-semicontinuous.
> On the other hand, the lower contour sets are not closed. To see this, note that $0 \succeq 1/2 - 1 / n$ for every $n$ since $f(0) \geq f(1/2 - 1/n)$. However, $1/2 \succ 0$ since $f(1/2) > f(0)$.

**How does this prove that the second definition does not imply the first?** I feel it shows rather the opposite. For the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}, x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $y = 0$, the counter example is:

$$x_n \to x, \quad x_n \precsim y.$$

But since $x \not\precsim y$, the pretext (which is the conditions of Statement $2$) is not satisfied.

Comment: Please give some more context here: What are "contour sets" (of a  relation??), and what does it mean for them to be closed? What kind of thins are $x_n$, $x$, and $y$? Is $\succsim$ a particular relation with a definition, or a placeholder name for an _arbitrary_ relation (on which set?)? Which of all these symbols are statements 1 and 2 supposed to be _definitions_ of?

Comment: @Troposphere Added all the necessary info. It's essentially the [preference relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preference_(economics)), but with the definitions and properties, I don't think that is required.

Comment: It is still unclear _which concept_ you want to consider statement 1/2 to be a definition of. The form of statement 1 looks like it might work as a definition of "continuous", but certainly statement 2 cannot be a definition of "continuous" because it does not even contain that word ...

Comment: @Troposphere Doesn't matter. I have changed the wording.

Comment: The example does not satisfy Statement 2, as you have explained. It does not satisfy Statement 1 either, as $\{y : y \precsim 0\}$ is not closed. Looking at the link you provided, it appears this is a counterexample to the (fawlty) definition of continuity in the Note at the bottom of the question, where only upper contour sets are required to be closed.